# Explanation of the default Debian sources?

Tags: debian, apt, configuration

So I've looked online and haven't found a clear explanation of the default Debian source list.

Specially, what do `main`, `updates`. `proposed-updates` and `security` mean in the context of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

I can make assumption about what they mean, but I haven't found enough information to understand if I should, for instance, include `updates` when switching to testing. https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList has some information, but not omits any information on `updates` or `security`.

I am fairly new to Debian, and while I think I could just muddle through the distinctions here, I'd really like just a clear explanation of what is going on instead of just copy and pasting lines into `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to differenciate between distributions and components. `wheezy`, `wheezy-updates`, `stable-proposed-updates` and `security` are distribution channels. They consist of components:

- `main` is for packages that are part of the debian core distribution ([see debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html))
- `contrib` is for extra packages
- `non-free` should be self-explanatory

Note that these components represent a classification by the debian developers mainly for the distribution packages of point releases like wheezy, jessie, etc.

The packages of the `wheezy` distribution, at the time of writing this the "stable" release, are for a stable and reliable system. The `wheezy-updates` are for urgent updates, see [this announcement](http://www.debian.org/News/2011/20110215) that are not part of `security`. `stable-proposed-updates` are updates that are in the process of being reviewed for inclusion in the next point release ([see documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/StableProposedUpdates)). `security` is for vulnerability fixes and is maintaned by a dedicated security team.

Maybe it helps to understand if we simplify all this: `wheezy` is for the full set of packages and consists of `main`, `contrib` and `non-free` so that you can install virtually every application that has been built for debian machines. `security` and `update` packages are for fixes and updates that can not wait till being frozen for the next point release.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this make more sense now. So you could theoretically run stable with just main and not get updates until the next point release? One thing I am still unclear on is, how does update and proposed-updates work for testing?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon See [here](http://www.debian.org/releases/proposed-updates.html) and [here](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3807816). From what I gather, `wheezy-proposed-updates` is a sneak peek into jessie(the upcoming debian release). `updates` are things that are safe to install. You can stay with just `wheezy`, but you should at least put the security repositories into your sources list. Also, `main` is, like `contrib` or `non-free` a **part of** `wheezy`/`stable`, not a release itself.

Comment: So what is `jessie-proposed-updates`?

Comment: See [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.html#t-p-u). It is for updates to the testing branch that do not go the long way through unstable. You may ask a debian developer though, he may be able to tell you more.

Comment: Thanks again, this was helpful. But I still feel like I don't fully understand what is going on with Debian's process.